# The past participle of "split": "split" or "splitted"?

Tags: verbs, past-participles

I have just written a question in the PPCG site, and now that I read it again I have just noticed that I have just written "split" and "splitted" randomly as the past participle of "to split":

> Can the number be split into powers of 2?
>   [The number] can be splitted into...
>   [The string] can be somehow split into numbers...

Since nobody seems to edit the question to fix any possible spelling mistakes, now I wonder: Are both forms valid? Or is one of them preferred or even invalid?

A simple Google search of "be split" and "be splitted" seems to return many more result for the "split" form (nearly a hundred times more). Maybe the "splitted" form is only used in specific contexts or countries?

Comment: The past tense, and past participle of "split" is "split".  I don't think that "splitted" is grammatical, though I dare say it gets used.

Comment: Splat! Sploot! Splut!

Comment: split, split, split, no doubt about it. Google searches return tons of non-native speakers' stuff. Ergo, one cannot use a simple Google search to make a determination.

Comment: So using SPLITTED is archaic, but does that mean that it is incorrect to use it nowadays?

Comment: What about "splitten"??

Answer (score 50, accepted):

***[Splitted](http://www.yourdictionary.com/splitted)*** appears to be a *nonstandard/obsolete* usage of the past tense of split:

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/split) notes that:

> (Language note)
>   The form split is used in the present tense and is the past tense and past participle of the verb.

and [Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/splitted) notes that ***splitted*** is:

> archaic past tense of SPLIT

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=splitted%2C%20split%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csplitted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csplit%3B%2Cc0) shows  very few  usage instances of splitted compared to split.

Comment: I was just about to add, archaic.

Comment: is there a general rule that says the same applies to any verb terminating with the letter t, like `put`, `cut`, etc ?